# Disable design mode in BO 4.2

Tags: business-objects

I need to disable the design mode tab for the view only users. I tried going to the group, customize and disable design mode but the tab and options are still there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried revoking the "Edit Objects" right?

Comment: We had to use the group customization and uncheck the design mode option. It was working for AD groups but not for the groups created in CMC.